# Visual Studio include files calling error - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, cegui

I'm building one sample from CEGUI, the SDK seems to be fine setle and the futher errors regarding the CEGUI on the log seems to come because of the errors with the includes from MVS. I can't affirm this since I'm not a C++ expert yet...I'm more experienced with Java..
Anyway, I saw a lot of posts talking about those compile errors, even since 2005, but some of them are just threw away, descontinued or the others that has an answer I couldn't fully understand (I supose until now they dont fit on my case...).

I can list here some posts I tryed to find an answer:

1. http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=205194
2. [error C2039: 'find' : is not a member of 'std'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868003/error-c2039-find-is-not-a-member-of-std)
3. [error C2039: 'memchr' : is not a member of '`global namespace''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531916/error-c2039-memchr-is-not-a-member-of-global-namespace)
4. [Syntax Errors in standard Microsoft files "iosfwd" & "atlconv.h" while compiling a VS2008 soln?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139429/syntax-errors-in-standard-microsoft-files-iosfwd-atlconv-h-while-compiling)

I don't really get whats going wrong on my programm, so I'm seeking for help here cos I've been stuck here for 2 days reading things and trying to solve my own, I don't know what else to do to go futher. **Could someone try to explain me what might be wrong with the compilation?**

```
 1>------ Build started: Project: Almost giving up, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>  main.cpp
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\iosfwd(517): error C2039: 'memcmp' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\iosfwd(517): error C3861: 'memcmp': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\iosfwd(523): error C2039: 'strlen' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\iosfwd(523): error C3861: 'strlen': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\iosfwd(546): error C2039: 'memchr' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\iosfwd(546): error C3861: 'memchr': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\iosfwd(559): error C2039: 'memset' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\iosfwd(559): error C3861: 'memset': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2651): error C2039: 'memset' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2651): error C3861: 'memset': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2656): error C2039: 'memset' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2656): error C3861: 'memset': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2661): error C2039: 'memset' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2661): error C3861: 'memset': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2685): error C2039: 'memset' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2685): error C3861: 'memset': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2692): error C2039: 'memset' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2692): error C3861: 'memset': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2699): error C2039: 'memset' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2699): error C3861: 'memset': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2964): error C2039: 'memcmp' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2964): error C3861: 'memcmp': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2970): error C2039: 'memcmp' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2970): error C3861: 'memcmp': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2976): error C2039: 'memcmp' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2976): error C3861: 'memcmp': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(3125): error C2039: 'memcmp' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(3125): error C3861: 'memcmp': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(3193): error C2039: 'memchr' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(3193): error C3861: 'memchr': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(3200): error C2039: 'memchr' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(3200): error C3861: 'memchr': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(3208): error C2039: 'memchr' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
    1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(3208): error C3861: 'memchr': identifier not found
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(44): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'utf8'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(44): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(46): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'utf32'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(46): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(51): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'encoded_char'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(51): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(51): error C2378: 'CEGUI::utf8' : redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(44) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::utf8'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(64): error C2504: 'AllocatedObject' : base class undefined
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(64): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(70): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'value_type'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(70): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(87): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(87): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(471): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(471): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(503): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(503): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(503): error C2535: 'CEGUI::String::String(const int)' : member function already defined or declared
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(471) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::String::String'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(862): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(862): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(897): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(897): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(935): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(935): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(936): error C2535: 'int CEGUI::String::compare(CEGUI::String::size_type,CEGUI::String::size_type,const int) const' : member function already defined or declared
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(897) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::String::compare'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1082): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '['
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1082): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1083): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1162): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1162): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1163): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1165): warning C4183: 'data': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1207): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1207): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'utf8'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1381): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1381): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1381): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1404): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1404): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1404): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1430): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1430): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1430): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1431): error C2535: 'CEGUI::String &CEGUI::String::assign(const int)' : member function already defined or declared
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1404) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::String::assign'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1454): error C2535: 'CEGUI::String &CEGUI::String::operator =(const int)' : member function already defined or declared
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1381) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::String::operator ='
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1728): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1728): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1728): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1751): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1751): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1751): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1778): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1778): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1778): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1779): error C2535: 'CEGUI::String &CEGUI::String::append(const int)' : member function already defined or declared
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1751) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::String::append'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1807): error C2535: 'CEGUI::String &CEGUI::String::operator +=(const int)' : member function already defined or declared
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(1728) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::String::operator +='
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2115): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2115): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2145): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2145): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2146): error C2535: 'CEGUI::String &CEGUI::String::insert(CEGUI::String::size_type,const int)' : member function already defined or declared
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2115) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::String::insert'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2747): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2747): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2779): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2779): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2812): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2812): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2813): error C2535: 'CEGUI::String &CEGUI::String::replace(CEGUI::String::size_type,CEGUI::String::size_type,const int)' : member function already defined or declared
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2747) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::String::replace'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2867): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2867): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2868): error C2535: 'CEGUI::String &CEGUI::String::replace(CEGUI::String::iterator,CEGUI::String::iterator,const int)' : member function already defined or declared
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(2779) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::String::replace'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3388): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3388): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3388): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3415): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3415): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3415): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3445): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3445): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3445): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3446): error C2535: 'CEGUI::String::size_type CEGUI::String::find(const int) const' : member function already defined or declared
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3388) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::String::find'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3496): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3496): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3496): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3497): error C2535: 'CEGUI::String::size_type CEGUI::String::rfind(const int) const' : member function already defined or declared
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3415) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::String::rfind'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3820): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3820): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3820): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3847): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3847): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3847): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3877): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3877): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3877): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3878): error C2535: 'CEGUI::String::size_type CEGUI::String::find_first_of(const int) const' : member function already defined or declared
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3820) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::String::find_first_of'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3925): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3925): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3925): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3926): error C2535: 'CEGUI::String::size_type CEGUI::String::find_first_not_of(const int) const' : member function already defined or declared
    1>          c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(3847) : see declaration of 'CEGUI::String::find_first_not_of'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(4302): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(4302): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(4302): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(4329): error C2327: 'CEGUI::String::utf8' : is not a type name, static, or enumerator
    1>c:\program files (x86)\cegui\cegui-0.8.2\cegui\include\cegui\string.h(4329): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skippe

d ==========
```

Code:

```
#include <RendererModules\Ogre\Renderer.h>

int main(){
// Bootstrap CEGUI::System with an OgreRenderer object that uses the
// default Ogre rendering window as the default output surface, an Ogre based
// ResourceProvider, and an Ogre based ImageCodec.
CEGUI::OgreRenderer& myRenderer =
CEGUI::OgreRenderer::bootstrapSystem();
}
```

The code comes from http://www.cegui.org.uk/docs/current/rendering_tutorial.html ; Even that doesnt say anything about include **xutility** or **iosfwd** I already tryed to do but the error is the same, I also tryed to open the files from VS but since I'm not an expert I couldnt fully understand to check for any errors, which I can't believe thats wrong since its a default file..

Comment: You might get more help if you show your main program, or a short strimmed down version that has the same problem. It smells like you haven't included some headers you need.

Comment: Check out the edit pls, the code is so simple that I forgot to post, sry

Comment: Have you done the other initialisation "Crazy Eddie" mentions? e.g. http://www.cegui.org.uk/docs/current/resprov_tutorial.html

Comment: I dont think so..He is very specific with this stretch of the spitch "For users of the Ogre3D library - or users with other custom resource providers not derived from DefaultResourceProvider - you should not follow the parts of this tutorial that deal with defining resouce groups and their directories (you should especially ignore any example code that casts to DefaultResouceProvider)." I'm using the ogre renderer and I'm trying just to compile the sample without any externals, what difference this would make?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I figured I would answer it.

If you include cegui-0.8.7\cegui\include\CEGUI in your MSVC include directories then it will suck up the String.h file in there and then will use THAT definition EVERYWHERE. Thus you start seeing things like xutility and iosfwd show up in the tainting.

Instead you must include ...\cegui-0.8.7\cegui\include so that it is scoped with CEGUI and does not confuse your entire build system.

Hope this helps someone!